# Underline for link in superscript text is at normal height

Tags: bug, meta, hyperlinks

[image: the bug]

As you can see above (top of the question), when there is superscript text within a URL, the underline is at the wrong height. [<sup>example</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com)

It should be at the superscript height.

Comment: While this is of course a bug in the superscript styling, it is also an example of where the `<small>` tag would be useful, which is [an open feature request since 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag).